# Affine geometry book for physicist

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, mathematical-physics, book-recommendation, affine-geometry

I'm looking for a textbook to help me with understanding the geometry of Galilean relativity and the Galilean group.  The reason is that I tried going through V.I. Arnold's Mathematical Methods, but got stuck on the very first chapter because I'm just not familiar enough with affine geometry or group theory.  So I want a good textbook on affine geometry, preferably using a coordinate-free approach, which goes over some physical applications including the Galilean group.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I hope Shafarevich & Remizov's *Linear Algebra and Geometry* is a good choice.